# Convergence of a sum to an integral using Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-physics

In physics, the following problem arises in the context of statistical mechanics. Let $L \gg 1$ be a fixed parameter. Let $\beta > 0$ be also fixed. Consider the following series:
$$\rho = \frac{1}{L^{3}}\sum_{p \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{3}}\frac{1}{e^{\beta(|p|^{2}-\mu)}-1}. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Here, $|p|^{2} = p_{1}^{2}+p_{2}^{2}+p_{3}^{2}$, as usual and $\mu$ is (another) parameter, which is supposed to be $-\infty < \mu \le 0$. One wants to take $L\to \infty$ and replace the sum by an integral:
$$\frac{1}{L^{3}}\sum_{p\in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{3}} \to \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int dp$$

My question is: what are the conditions which allow such replacement or, putting in another words, what conditions guarantee convergence of the sum into an integral?

Let me just explain the motivation of the question. It turns out that, if one replaces the series by an integral without worrying about the convergence, it leads to a very strange physical consequence where the density of the system is bounded when $\mu \to 0^{-}$. The explanation in the physics literature is that $\mu$ is itself a function of $L^{3}$, implicitly by (\ref{1}). Hence, one has to be careful when taking the limit $L\to \infty$. So, if the parameters $\beta$ and $\rho$ are such that, in the limit $L\to \infty$, $\mu \to 1$, then the term $(e^{-\beta\mu}-1)^{-1}$ (the term with $p=0$) in the sum (\ref{1}) diverges, and one cannot replace the sum by an integral.

So, getting back to my question, I wonder if that ensuring that every term in the sum (\ref{1}) is not divergent for every $\mu$ (also in the limit $\mu \to 0$) is sufficient to ensure that the sum converges to an integral.

Comment: If the function you are summing/integrating is integrable with a finite result, this is justified. The sum is actually a valid Reimann sum for the integral. In your particular example, you have a problem along the circle $|p|^2 = \mu$. The integral does not converge there, whereas the sum exists for most values of $L$, only becoming undefined when a lattice point lies on the circle.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. So, the "a posteriori" justification is a valid argument, here? I mean, replace the sum by an integral and check for what values of $\mu$ the integral is finite or not. The values which the integral are not finite are the ones the limit cannot be taken.

Comment: If the function is integrable, that means *all* limits of Riemann sums converge to the integral value as the maximum diameter of the partitions goes to $0$. Your sum is such a limit, so it must converge to the integral. Thus all you need to show is the function is integrable. If the integral diverges to $\infty$, then all limits of Riemann sums will as well. If the integral diverges in other ways, then your sum could converge or not. But even if it converges, you don't have a integration to tell you the limit.